# No suitable method for makeText() - Toast (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have defined a simple `Toast` that is going to display "log added" when a file has been written to. The rest of the code is just the rest of the method that writes EditText content to a file called log.txt.

I have used `getActivityContext()`, `this` and `MainActivity` as the `context` arguments in an attempt to get this to work. However for some reason it still doesn't. I have imported the correct classes, I have checked the `manifest`, but `MainActivity` is correctly declared. I have searched for the answer to this for quite sometime as I knew it would be regarded as a novice issue. But never the less, it would be nice to get an answer :)

```
//SEND ARRIVAL TIME
public void sendArrTime(View view) {

    btnArr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnArr);
    btnArr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Opens log.txt
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("arrlog.txt", MODE_APPEND));

            //Writes contents to file
            etArr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etArr);
            String text = etArr.getText().toString();
            out.write(text);
            out.write('\n');

            //close file
            out.close();

            //Confirmation Toast
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Log added", 3).show();


            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: Use `MainActivity.this` instead of `this`.

Comment: Note that "this" is actually refering to the object this is encapsulating, which is a View.OnClickListener()

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int)):

> duration  int: How long to display the message. Either LENGTH_SHORT or LENGTH_LONG

So, either Toast.LENGTH_SHORT or Toast.LENGTH_LONG. Not '3'

Comment: You can set it with a numerical value, but short is 0 and long is 1, Its better to use the built in constants though.

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(this,"Log added"+password,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the proper context `MainActivity.this` NOT `this`.

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Log added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: I have changed it to MainActivity.this and it is now saying "Incompatible Types". Required: 'android.widget.Toast' Found: 'void'.